# Google Apps Scripts - how send data from scropt to page using post method?

Tags: google-apps-script, methods, http-post

I have Apps Script:

```
function editSheet(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getId();
  var filename = ss.getName();
  var sheetname = ss.getSheetName();
  var maxCol = ss.getLastColumn();
  var maxRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var gid = ss.getSheetId();
  
  var values = ss.getRange(sheetname+"!A1:"+maxRow).getValues();

  var json = JSON.stringify(values);
  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "contentType" : "multipart/form-data",
    "sheet" : sheet,
    "filename":filename,
    "values" : json
  };
  var url = 'http://mydomian.pl/app.php';

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

but Apps Script not send POST data. http://mydomian.pl/app.php - can get data method post

> echo "values: ".$_POST['values'];

... What is wrong? Or some other way?

Answer (score 2):

Post body is [payload](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#advanced-parameters)

```js
  const options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "payload": payload
  };
```

So in your case, that would look something like this:

```
var data = {
  "sheet" : sheet,
  "filename":filename,
  "values" : json
};

var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
};

var url = 'http://mydomian.pl/app.php';

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
```

Answer (score 1):

I try like u say..:

```
  var json = JSON.stringify(values);
  var payload = json;
  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "payload" : payload
  };
```

in my file I try

> echo $_POST['payload'];

nothing work

Comment: `payload` is not a name. It is the post body itself.

Comment: ok i find 
` $data=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),1); `
but data is not sort...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: OK I find way... write sort function and sort values before send data :-) `   values=sortObjectByKeys(values); ` function `function sortObjectByKeys(o) {
    return Object.keys(o).sort().reduce((r, k) => (r[k] = o[k], r), {});
}`